# MySQL Workbench - Create new server instance error

Tags: mysql-workbench, mac-os-x

When attempting to create a new server instance I get an error at the 'Test Settings' step of the creation wizard.

The error:

```
What check_admin_commands/local
Operation failed: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start is invalid
```

I'm using MAMP and new to OSX so I'm not sure what the problem is here. I can't find the directory `/usr` on OSX, should I be changing Workbench's configuration to look elsewhere for `mysql.server`?

Comment: I'm having the very same issue. Really frustrated. Have you found a solution.

Comment: @John - Looks like someone posted a link to a solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code-remind.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/on-macbookpro-10.html

NOTE: Where the author suggests using the path '/Applications/MAMP/bin/stoptMysql.sh' at the end... there's a typo.

Should be '/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh'

Comment: Thanks, looks like I don't have a my.cnf file, will have to make one.

Comment: Please can you edit in a summary of the contents of the link Rory?